# Why does change() called only for receiving radio?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following handler setup

```
form.find("input[name=url_source]").change(function() {
            updateUrlSource(jQuery(this))
            });
```

I was thinking it will be attached to all radio buttons with the name. But actually I see in debugger, that only one call occurs and only first condition satisfies below:

```
function updateUrlSource(source) {
   if( source.is(':checked') ) {
      // ...
   }
   else {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Is this true? Why?

Comment: My guess is the change event is only happening on the one that initiated the change (the one that was clicked), therefore .is(':checked') will always be true.

Comment: use `.on("click",function()`  insteand

Comment: Those are radio buttons - they must have the same name to be in the same group.

Comment: @nathanhayfield all radio buttons inside one radio group have got to have same `name`

Comment: @nathanhayfield It's normal to give radio buttons the same name, that's how you identify the set.

Comment: @dims Please post your HTML too

Comment: I don't think any of you are understanding his question. The problem he's having is that when you click a radio button, it causes two changes: the new button is checked, and the old button is unchecked. He expects two events to fire, but only one of them does (for the new button).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But actually I see in debugger, that only one call occurs and only first condition satisfies below:

Correct, `change` is only fired on the input that *received* the check, not the others that (may have) lost it. Details buried somewhere [in this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)), but I believe this is the critical bit:

> If the element is mutable, then: The pre-click activation steps consist of setting the element's checkedness to true. The canceled activation steps consist of setting the element's checkedness to false. **The activation behavior is to fire a simple event that bubbles named `change` at the element.**

*(My emphasis, and many thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for the assist!)*

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ugudaf/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Radio Behavior</title>
  <style>
    label {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>(Look in the console for the output as you click...</p>
  <hr>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="g1-1"> Group 1 one</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="g1-2"> Group 1 two</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="g1-3"> Group 1 three</label>
  <hr>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="g2-1"> Group 2 one</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="g2-2"> Group 2 two</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="g2-3"> Group 2 three</label>
</body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $("input[type=radio][name=group1]").change(function() {
        console.log("group 1 changed to: " + this.id);
      });
      $("input[type=radio][name=group2]").change(function() {
        console.log("group 2 changed to: " + this.id);
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Somoene else "got it".

Comment: The relevant line in the documentation is _The activation behavior is to fire a simple event that bubbles named __change__ at the element._  This refers to the element being activated, i.e. the button you click on.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks! I *thought* that was the relevant line, then decided I wasn't sure enough to actually *say* so. :-)

Comment: I had to read that paragraph about 5 times to convince myself.